# Getting NullPointer Exception while Executing MapReduce Program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I am getting NullPointer exception while running Map Reduce Program.
Please help in understanding why this error is coming.

```
public class AvgDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

    @Override
    public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

        Job job=Job.getInstance();
        job.setJar("AvgSalary.jar");

        job.setMapperClass(AvgMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);



        //job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        job.setReducerClass(AvgReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(arg0[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(arg0[1]));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
    }

    public void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {

        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new AvgDriver(), args));
    }
}




public class AvgMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, DoubleWritable> {

    public void map(LongWritable key , Text value , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String values=value.toString();
        String [] val=values.split("\t");

        double convertVal=Double.parseDouble(val[2]);

        context.write(NullWritable.get(), new DoubleWritable(convertVal));
    }

} 


public class AvgReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, DoubleWritable, NullWritable, DoubleWritable> {

    double total=0.0;
    int count=0;

    public void Reduce(NullWritable key , Iterator<DoubleWritable> value , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        while (value.hasNext()) {
            total = total+ ((DoubleWritable) value.next()).get();
            count++;
        }

        total=total/count;

        context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(total));
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace must be pointing to some line of code. Which one is that ?

Comment: [cloudera@quickstart PracticeNew]$ hadoop jar AvgSalary.jar com.ankur.practics.AvgDriver /user/hdfs/empSal.txt /user/hdfs/output15
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: you can see in above stack trace there is no class mention where this exception is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **static** in main method. Update as below.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
```

Comment: I made another program where Job job = Job.getInstance () is working fine.

Comment: did you try this ? did it fix the issue ? where you are getting the null pointer , you will now the particular java line from stack trace , please post that.

Comment: I tried but still same error.

Comment: cloudera@quickstart PracticeNew]$ hadoop jar AvgSalary.jar com.ankur.practics.AvgDriver /user/hdfs/empSal.txt /user/hdfs/output11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
  
  Configuration conf=new Configuration();
  
  Job job=new Job(conf);
  job.setJar("AvgSalary.jar");
  
  job.setMapperClass(AvgMapper.class);
  job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

Comment: I have updated my answer , please check

Comment: Yes it is working now.. Thanks .. :)